# UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput placeholder text won't set

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uialertview

I have an app that uses a UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput alert view.  Everything works fine with the exception that the password field's placeholder text has some strange behavior.  On my sim it refuses to change from 'Password' regardless of what I set it as.  And Ive been having reports that it flip flops between 'Password" and the value I wish to set it at.  This seems to be all iOS7 related.

I am attempting to set these values in the 'willPresentAlertView' delegate.

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    ...


   else if (alertView.tag == UIAlertViewTagInactivityTimeOut)
   {
    badgeNumberTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    verifyBadgeNumberTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];

    [badgeNumberTextField setPlaceholder:@"Badge Number"];
    [verifyBadgeNumberTextField setPlaceholder:@"Verify Badge Number"];

    [verifyBadgeNumberTextField setSecureTextEntry:NO];

    [badgeNumberTextField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:ALERT_VIEW_TEXTFIELD_TEXT_FONT]];
    [verifyBadgeNumberTextField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:ALERT_VIEW_TEXTFIELD_TEXT_FONT]];

    [badgeNumberTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad];
    [verifyBadgeNumberTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad];

    [badgeNumberTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [verifyBadgeNumberTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];

    [badgeNumberTextField setDelegate:self];
    [verifyBadgeNumberTextField setDelegate:self];

    ...
     //other code 
  }
}
```

Comment: I notice you have the else-if as what you're showing. What is set as the if section of that if-else if

Comment: Its basically the same allocations but different placeholders for another UIAlertView with the same style.  The placeholders there are 'Trailer Number' and 'Verify Trailer.'  It should be noted though, that alert view always works correctly.  To add some weird complexity to the situation

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried set the placeholder where you create the UIAlertView?

Try this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"Username placeholder";
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].placeholder = @"Password placeholder";
[alert show];
```